# Why do template strings (``) execute preceding token as a function?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, template-strings

I encountered an error today - `TypeError: "fa" is not a function` - and after a short investigation, I found the cause. I had forgotten a comma in an object literal, which left me with what amounted to a string followed by a template string, essentially this: ``` "fa"`` ```. Having seen `not a function` I expected to find some offending parentheses and found this curious, so I deepened my investigation in a Node REPL.

```
''``               // TypeError: '' is not a function
'foo'``            // TypeError: 'foo' is not a function
1``                // TypeError: 1 is not a function
(() => 'foobar')`` //'foobar'
```

Okay, so I found out that a template string seems to work similarly to putting parentheses after a token. Curiouser and curiouser.

I wondered whether it passes along any arguments, so I wrote this:

```
function showArgs () {
  return arguments
}

showArgs()                  // {}
showArgs``                  // { '0': [ '' ] }
showArgs`foo`               // { '0': [ 'foo' ] }
showArgs`foo${'bar'}`       // { '0': [ 'foo', '' ], '1': 'bar' }
showArgs`foo${'bar'}${1}`   // { '0': [ 'foo', '', '' ], '1': 'bar', '2': 1 }
showArgs(`foo${'bar'}${1}`) // { '0': 'foobar1`' }
```

What is going on here?

The arguments obviously have something to do with the template string, as they can be used to construct it by concatinating the *n*th array item with the *n + 1*th argument and joining them all, but why is the template string executing the preceding token with those arguments?

Comment: See this golf answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/102259/31224 to see an interesting use of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Look into [tagged template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_template_literals).**

> A more advanced form of template literals are *tagged* template literals. With them you are able to modify the output of template literals using a function. The first argument contains an array of string literals [...]. The second, and each argument after the first one, are the values of the processed (or sometimes called *cooked*) substitution expressions [...]. In the end, your function returns your manipulated string.

---

An example from MDN:

```
var a = 5;
var b = 10;

function tag(strings, ...values) {
  console.log(strings[0]); // "Hello "
  console.log(strings[1]); // " world "
  console.log(strings[2]); // ""
  console.log(values[0]);  // 15
  console.log(values[1]);  // 50

  return "Bazinga!";
}

tag`Hello ${ a + b } world ${ a * b }`;
// "Bazinga!"
```